# How does dereferencing the pointer is changing the value in this code snippet?

Tags: c++, pointers, hex, dereference

Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
#include "iostream"


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  unsigned long var  = 0x04030201;
  unsigned char* ptr = NULL;

  ptr = (unsigned char*) &var;
  ptr[2] = 0x05;
  std::cout << std::hex << var << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output: 0x4050201

Comment: And what output did you expect? What do you think `ptr[2] = 0x05` does?

Comment: C++ allows you to do all manner of strange and wonderful and utterly stupid things. And like many other things in C++, which are strange, wonderful and utterly stupid change based on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not only dereferencing the pointer, you're updating the value as well.

```
 ptr[2] = 0x05;
```

updates the value at 3rd octet. So, for a starting value of

```
 (0x) 04 03 02 01
```

it gets modified like

```
 (0x) 04 05 02 01    
         ^--------- ptr[2]
```

To add, from `C11`, chapter 6.3.2.3,

> *[...] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.*

So, in a [little-endian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), it looks like

```
ptr[0] = 01
ptr[1] = 02
ptr[2] = 03
ptr[3] = 04
```

and you're modifying `ptr[2]`, so the value change is reflected in result.

Comment: IIRC `std::cout << var;` results in UB due to an  aliasing concern. Code may  assume `var` did not change due to `ptr[2] = 0x05;`.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is an unsigned long variable, which is 4 bytes in a 32-bit system and 8 bytes in a 64-bit system.

`ptr` is a pointer to an unsigned char. `ptr` looks at the "first" byte of `var`, due to the fact that it is a **char** pointer.

`ptr[2]` is as '*(ptr + 2)' in pointer arithmetics, and therefore this expression give us the address of 2 bytes ahead and dereferencing the pointer.

So, in the end, the hex value `0x05` will be assigned to the 3rd byte of `var`.